# Zoom in/out Xcode Storyboards

Tags: xcode, zooming, xcode-storyboard

Zooming in/out on a macOS storyboard in Xcode does not seem to be possible:

- Editor -> Zoom menu is greyed out
- No + or - buttons on storyboard

I want to zoom out of the storyboards to see more of a view controller, as I can only see a portion.

**Edit:**
This is Xcode 9.4.1
Screenshot of `Main.storyboard`:

[screen shot of main.storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvzi6.png)

Zoom Menu:
[Zoom menu greyed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oDnX.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of xcode you got?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't (in macOS app projects).

Comment: Then you should accept that answer, and maybe leave a comment there. Adding a self answer that only says "do what the other answer says", there is no point in doing that!

Answer (score 6):

You could change the zoom level by:

- keep pushing the <kbd>option</kbd> button.
- and then scroll the mouse wheel.

The benefit that you will get by following this approach is that you would be able to change the level with the desired percentage, instead of being sticked with the provided zoom percentages by clicking the +/- buttons.

Comment: I want to zoom out the storyboard to see more of the VC, not just make it smaller.

Comment: @Benj just try to scroll up and down! Therefore it would be zoom in/out.